# Handling asynchronous functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 javascript functions that both have their own ajax requests. In pseudo code, it works as follows:

```
fetch_menu_item {
//Make ajax call to get proper data
success: (res) => {
  this.setState({items_ordered: res})
}
}

print_receipt {
  this.fetch_menu_item();
//Make consts for waiter/date/time and items ordered
  ordered : this.items_ordered
//Make another AJAX call to post data to the printer
}
```

So here's what I don't get. Since Javascript is an asynchronous, I think I need to call the fetch_menu_item function in print_receipt otherwise the items_ordered variable will just be empty. Is it possible at all to have this running in one function or is it better practice to keep these split apart?

Comment: I find it a bit difficult to help with this pseudo code, but in general, if you have an async function that changes some variable then the function needs to provide a way to notify the caller (or a subscriber) that it is done and the new value of the variable can be read.

Comment: In native javascript your best bet is to chain your function calls or handle them via delegates. [ES2017 introduced await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) which essentially handles those continuation functions in the background for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want to first grab your menu items and then print your receipt. So you would probably want to make a method to take a list of your menu items to grab and then have a callback function which would be your print receipt.

```
    fetch_menu_items(item_list, callback){
        /*forEach menu item asynchronously fetch with fetch_menu_item and
        make a list of promises*/
        promise.all(listofpromises).then(callback);

    }
    fetch_menu_item {
    //Make ajax call to get proper data
    success: (res) => {
      this.setState({items_ordered: res})
    }
    }

    print_receipt {
      this.fetch_menu_item();
    //Make consts for waiter/date/time and items ordered
      ordered : this.items_ordered
    //Make another AJAX call to post data to the printer
    }
```

then just pass print_receipt as the callback for fetch_menu_items